# How to refactor a UITableViewCell configuration code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with a single custom table view cell that over time has resulted to a somewhat convoluted structure and I'm hoping to simplify and improve it. Basically in the current form, there are images and buttons on the left and right side of the cell and possibly two different labels in the middle.

The cells are configured based on the entry they are representing, the section of table view and the state of the tableview and therefore both the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath and willDisplayCell has become quite cluttered. The configuration includes hiding/unhiding of the non-label subviews and possibly changing the frame of the UILabels.

How would you suggest going about structuring and improving such a code and when would you start using different custom cell classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create custom subclasses for each entry type you have.  Create a method on each cell subclass called something like

```
-(void)configureCell:(Entry *)entry
{
   //do configuration stuff here
}
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, do something like:

```
Entry *entry = self.entryArray[indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell;
switch( entry.entryType )
{
    case EntryTypeOne:
        CellTypeOne *cCell = (CellTypeOne *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellTypeOne" forIndexPath:indexPath 
        [cCell configureCell:entry];
        cell = cCell;
        break; 
    case EntryTypeTwo:
        CellTypeTwo *cCell = (CellTypeTwo *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellTypeTwo" forIndexPath:indexPath 
        [cCell configureCell:entry];
        cell = cCell;
        break;   
}

return cCell;
```

Just some ideas as I don't actually know how your code is set up or how you differentiate between types of entries.

Comment: This sounds good Jonah, how would you draw the line in terms of splitting to custom classes though? for instance I have a button that when the user hits, will result to hiding of the original button and unhiding of different button (select/deselect). Would you create to subclasses for each of these states?

Comment: You can, but it isn't necessary. You could have the button click toggle a BOOL value in your entry called something like didClick and then in your configureCell logic hide/show ui elements based on the state of didClick. You just have to make sure to reload your table data whenever the button is clicked as well as setting your didClick property. Personally, I would create separate subclasses. Makes the logic simpler.

Comment: Another minor question, in terms of actions on the custom cells, would you target them at the ViewController or the Cell and use delegation?

Comment: I try to keep my business logic out of my view controllers. Wherever possible, I try to limit the scope of my view controllers to functionality affecting it's direct subviews.

Comment: Also, there are a couple of other options instead of using delegation. You can send a notification using NSNotificationCenter or assign blocks to your cells in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.